# How to write outline constructor that has been inheritance?

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to write **OUTLINE** inheritance constructor in c++.
I am not sure that's possible.
I have only written inline inheritance constructor.

If there are some way to write, can you share it.

Thanks.

Here's my code.

```
 18 public: 
 19         FullTimeEmployee(int eid, string name, int salary):Employee(eid, name);
 20         int getSalary(){ return salary; }
 21 };
 22 
 23 FullTimeEmployee::FullTimeEmployee(int eid, string name, int salary):Employee(eid, name){
 24         this->salary = salary;
 25 }
```

Comment: Did you mean: I want to construct a constructor of a derived class outside of the class code?

Comment: yes, sorry about that.

Comment: What happens with the above code? Do you get an error when you tried it?

Comment: yes it's give this error. ```exec.cpp:19:72: error: expected '{' or ','
        FullTimeEmployee(int eid, string name, int salary):Employee(eid, name);```
                                                                              ^

Comment: On line 19, add a `{}` before the `;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the line 19, you don't have to declare to add the derived `:Employee(eid, name)` anymore. simply make it like this

```
FullTimeEmployee(int eid, string name, int salary);
```

so the code would probably like this if it is a whole program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Employee{
    public:
      Employee(int eid, string name){}
};

class FullTimeEmployee:Employee{
    private: 
      int salary;
      int eid = 10;
      string name = "hei";
    public: 
      FullTimeEmployee(int eid, string name, int salary);
      int getSalary(){ return salary; }    
};
  
FullTimeEmployee::FullTimeEmployee(int eid, string name, int salary):Employee(eid, name){
    this->salary = salary;
};


int main()
{
    FullTimeEmployee f(10, "yuza", 200);
    cout<<f.getSalary();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a constructor of a derived class something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class base { // the base class
    int x, y;

public:
    base() {} // default constructor
    base(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {};
};

class derived : public base {
    int m, n;
public:
    derived(int, int); // derived class's constructor with its signature

    void print(void) {
        std::cout << m << ' ' << n << std::endl;
    }
};

derived :: derived(int Dx, int Dy) { // coding the constructor of derived class
                                     // outside of the class.
    m = Dx;
    n = Dy;
}

int main(void) {
    derived d(5, 3); // instantiating the object of the derived class

    d.print(); // will print 5 <space> 3

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah it's correct but it also has to inherit the parameters. In this case let's say **derived** has four parms in constructor(Dx, Dy, a, b). so **a** and **b** will be passed to base constructor.

Comment: And what will happen to the Dx and Dy?